# Expression not in GROUP BY key with UDAF

Tags: sql, hive, hql

My UDAF returns an array, but I'm getting a SemanticException, so that probably isn't relevant.

```
ADD JAR udaf.jar;
SELECT a, b, c,
             sum(i) i,
             sum(l) l,
             myUDAF(f, ud, uh, i, tb, l, tl, (co + cov), tco, lb, lr) ms
      FROM table
GROUP BY a, b, c;
```

Gives

```
SemanticException [Error 10025]: Expression not in GROUP BY key 'lr'
```

I get the same error even when I explicitly add 'lr' to the group by (which should not be necessary).

Comment: Try adding "ms" to the "group by".

Comment: The error suggest that the engine thinks you want the UDF run on the grouped column values. If you actually want it run on the individual rows you probably need a nested query and then add `ms` to the group by clause, as Gordon Linoff suggests.

Comment: When I try adding ms to the group by, I get "Invalid table alias or column reference 'ms': (possible column names are: ..." 

I am not sure that it suggests that it wants the UDAF run on grouped columns. To test this, I tried putting 'c' in the last position of the UDAF, which gve me "Expression not in GROUP BY key 'c'."

Whatever is given as the last parameter will be what is in the error

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this a long time ago, but didn't post it. Basically, you need to create the function after adding the jar. Adding something like

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION myUDAF as
'com...udaf.myUDAF';
```

will make it work